# Increase partition size to include more data in hazelcast map

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am using `hazelcast` as `cache cluster`.

I have three map store for three tables in mysql. Each table has 100000 records.
I am starting three instance of `hazelcast` to load these tables in my map with `different maps`.
But issue.

When i start first instance and call load all for first table it loads all `100000` entries but when i call second instance to load second table with same process it loads `49449` entries and in third instance it only loads 33249 entries only.

I am using three different java codes to load these tables.
My partition size default is `271` 
I was looking for error but there is no error shown and data loaded always the same as explained above.
Could you please help me what could be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you log the number of keys that have been loaded by each of your MapLoader/MapStore implementation when the MapLoader.loadAllKeys() is called?

Perhaps this can shed some light on the situation. If the number isn't 100k here, then the issue is not inside HZ.

Comment: So at least we know that you are able to get the right number of keys from the DB; this is a solid beginning. What do you mean with 'hazelcast instance for each table'? Are they not going to form a cluster or have you given them different partition groups or something?

Comment: I have craeteed a jabva main program for each instance to represent it like node structure so there are three nodes in thsi cluster as you can see in config implementation it is defined for each map store so these three are on three different ports

Comment: MY issues is when i query a map which is having less data than 100k and that key does not exists in the map it gives me null but it should have gone to data bases to fetch record and update in map also.

Comment: public Set<Long> loadAllKeys() {
  Set<Long> allKeys = null;
        try {
         allKeys = new HashSet<Long>();
           ResultSet rs =  con.createStatement().executeQuery(String.format("select id from City"));
            while (rs.next()) {
                Long key = rs.getLong(1);
                allKeys.add(key);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        finally {
        }
        return allKeys;                                              }

Comment: MY code is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26396677/mapstore-not-loading-data-from-data-base-hazelcast

Comment: I have updated the loadAllkeys method with the implementation above

Comment: I think the 3 nodes you have created, are forming a cluster, unless you did something explicitly to prevent this. This means that your environment is something else than you think it is. But this should not change the behaviour of what you are seeing. Can you create a unit test, that doesn't rely on mysql, that proves a bug exist and send it to our github? https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues So one of our engineers can have a look at it?

Comment: Without sql i was able to work on it but when i used sql this issue started still i will amke a test case for it but if you can give me a link where i can share my current code then that can be reviewed also. If taht is possible for you

Comment: i am trying to create a test case for it but as i am very new to hazel cast. This is a standard mapstore implementation which i took from hazelcast documentation page.